# Google oauth2 migration issue, missing openid_id

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-openid

I noticed that since recently my "login with Google" script doesn't work correctly anymore. After some debugging it seems that the main value `openid_id` is not being returned anymore.

I am correctly receiving `access_token` `id_token` `iss` `iat` `exp` `at_hash` `aud` `sub` `azp` & `email`.

`openid_id` used to be string such as `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOa....`

This is how I identified users, and have them stored locally in my database.

Can I still receive the `openid_id` ? If so, how?

If `openid_id` in the old string isn't going to be available anymore, how can we convert the new identification tokes to the old ones? So that I can map those, so old users can still login.

Comment: wild guess Extract the sub field from the token-request response. This is the OpenID Connect identifier https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration

Comment: Yep the sub field I can extract no problem. But as the openid_id value is now missing for me, I don't know who to map to what account.

Comment: So far I still do not see any way how to get the openid_id value of users after jan 1st 2017. I'm worried for my excising users database which only contains openid_id values to verify who is who.

Comment: I suspect this is why google gave everyone two years to fix the data before shutting it down.

Comment: Still seems odd there is no way to get this openid_id value. Even if I made all the right migration steps, say a user never logged into my site in the last 2 years, their ID would have never been converted. I have 100's of thousands of users who haven't logged in over 2 years. There has to be a way to convert the https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id? values to something we can match is to which is currently returned by their api.

Comment: I am not 100 sure about opened rules but I know that refresh tokens that haven't been used in six months expire.   If they haven't been on your site in two years they are going to have to authenticate again.    Supposed I could go check the rfc for openid connect

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you were hit by the deprecation hammer.

> web applications that use the deprecated OpenID 2.0 for Google login,
>   see OpenID 2.0 (Deprecated). For information about using the
>   deprecated OpenID 2.0 authentication with Google Apps (hosted)
>   accounts, see OpenID API for Google Apps accounts (Deprecated).

[Migration timetable](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable) says

> mapping of OpenID 2.0 identifiers to OAuth 2.0 identifiers will continue to work until January 1, 2017.

Solution:  [Migrating from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration)

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm now trying to map the old openid_id data to the new 'sub' data. But as 'openid_id' isn't returned to me anymore, it's impossible for me to link the right accounts. How can I get Google to return the 'openid_id' values again?

Comment: you cant this system was shut down in 2015 you have had two years to fix the data in your database to map things.   Now its gone.

Comment: It says on the migration page: Tip: If you overwrite a user's OpenID 2.0 identifier (openid_id) and need to find it again, you can repeat the process of including an openid.realm parameter in an authentication request and mapping the returned openid_id to the new sub ID.

Comment: Seems its still possible. I just dont understand how.

Comment: It seams that was possible prior to mapping of OpenID 2.0 identifiers to OAuth 2.0 identifiers will continue to work until January 1, 2017.   I am not all that sure it is still posible

Comment: take one of your ids and feed it to this https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123  I am kind of digging around in documentation here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132915/discussion-between-mr-boon-and-daimto).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with disappeared **openid_id**. After "digging" in API answers I've noticed, that there is **email** parameter here. The same email we store in database, so now we can link existed profiles with new **sub** parameter on-the-fly, and solve our problem. At least, there is no need to find out old openid_id parameter.